# Android Studio 3.2. When buildType = release -> Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-build

Android Studio 3.2

In my project/app.build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

In my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("app/keystore.properties")))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 421
        versionName "2.1.421"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        // to fix problem when annotation not build on release
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ['resourcePackageName': "com.myproject"]
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['KEY_ALIAS_RELEASE']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['KEY_PASSWORD_RELEASE']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['STORE_FILE_RELEASE'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['STORE_PASSWORD_RELEASE']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            configBuildType(delegate, "Release instance name", "Release app name", "beta")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
        debug {
            configBuildType(delegate, "Debug name instance", "Debug name, null)

            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes = defaultConfig.versionName + " " + name
            ext.betaDistributionEmailsFilePath = "app/beta_distribution_emails.txt"
        }
    } 
}

def configBuildType(buildType, instanceName, appName, appIdSuffix) {   
    buildType.resValue("string", "app_name", appName)
    buildType.applicationIdSuffix(appIdSuffix)
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "INSTANCE_NAME", instanceName)
}
// must be version 4.5.2
def AAVersion = '4.5.2'

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:ormlite:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec
    implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.1'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:ormlite-api:$AAVersion"   

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

When `buildType = debug` the project success build and run. Nice.
But when `buildType = release` I get error:

```
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalReleaseD:\myproject\app: Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]
D:\myproject\app: Error: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

   Explanation for issues of type "DuplicatePlatformClasses":
   There are a number of libraries that duplicate not just functionality of
   the Android platform but using the exact same class names as the ones
   provided in Android -- for example the apache http classes. This can lead
   to unexpected crashes.

   To solve this, you need to either find a newer version of the library which
   no longer has this problem, or to repackage the library (and all of its
   dependencies) using something like the jarjar tool, or finally, rewriting
   the code to use different APIs (for example, for http code, consider using
   HttpUrlConnection or a library like okhttp).

2 errors, 0 warnings
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your app/build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
}
```